# How to increase a global variable in a function and use/increment multiple times thereafter in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have 2 Python files:

**functions.py**

```
global counter
counter = 0

def printC():
    print(counter)

def increaseC():
    counter += 1
```

and a **main.py**

```
from functions import printC
from functions import increaseC

printC()
increaseC()
```

The first function prints the 0 with no problem but then i get that error message: 
**counter += 1 

UnboundLocalError: local variable 'counter' referenced before assignment**

My question is: How can i increase that global variable that way than i can print the same way like this:

```
from functions import printC
from functions import increaseC

printC()
increaseC()
printC()
```

To get the second print with 1 value?

Comment: Use global keyword inside a function if you want to change the variable.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using global variables in a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/423379/using-global-variables-in-a-function)

Comment: `global counter` inside `increaseC` since because you do `counter += 1`, counter is looked into the local namespace of  `increaseC`, but it's not there. `global counter` tells it to look in the global scope

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `global` keyword inside a function if you want to change the variable.

```
def increaseC():
    global counter
    counter += 1
```